# Angular.forEach does not return the last item in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach

```
       var items = [];

        //angular.forEach(localStorage, function(value, key){
        //    items.push({
        //        'id'    : key,
        //        'text'  : value
        //    });
        //    console.log(value);
        //});
        for(var key in localStorage){
            if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                //console.log(localStorage[row]);
                items.push({
                    'id'    : key,
                    'text'  : localStorage[key]
                });
            }
        }
        return items;
```

The commented code returns array of two elements, while simple "for in" loop return all the values form the localStorage object (actually there are three items).

I don't get why the hell angular.forEach does not iterate the last item in object?

Everything should be ok according to the docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Does `localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)` return true for all elements? Can you put together a jsfiddle or a plunkr?

Comment: actually the code  working perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/jq6e04qa/ checkout whether there is any other issues

Comment: Here is my localStorage i.imgur.com/j7GocsN.jpg
Here I consoled keys which are iterated http://i.imgur.com/BbgQqGp.jpg
Here is console http://i.imgur.com/j90YyzH.jpg

Comment: OP is right, it's iterating 2 only when localStorage has integers as key. [https://jsfiddle.net/hru2k47u/](https://jsfiddle.net/hru2k47u/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I found from my debugging.

As you have set keys of `localStorage` as integers (though it will be saved as string) but for libraries like jQuery and Angular, they will consider it as number and will iterate it over object for that particular size of object. (here 3 in your case.)

By printing all values with jQuery (https://jsfiddle.net/9n4btgob/) it's giving me `0` also as output and it's value is undefined. So iteration will be over at 2.

Thus angular is using jQlite so it will output same results.
https://jsfiddle.net/hru2k47u/

Here by setting first value of `localStorage` as `0` will solve problem.

Working With angular : https://jsfiddle.net/hru2k47u/1/
working with jQuery : https://jsfiddle.net/9n4btgob/2/

#### OR

you can append any alphabet to keys.

### Update:

After debugging jQuery more I found that `isArrayLike` function is causing the issue. Because this function returns true for `localStorage` where keys are numeric, thus it will start for loop till it's length and iterate over it. so Last property won't execute.

```
if ( isArrayLike( obj ) ) {
            length = obj.length;
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Or do it properly with `Object.Keys`, its what its designed for  `Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(x => console.log(x))`. Edit: didn't mean to bring your answer down (sounded bad). Its some good research.

Comment: I've seen that, it will work with no doubt. And I've tested `lodash` will work even with `_.forIn`, lots of ways to achieve this. Thanks for pointing that out.